# inserting NULL into DATE or tinyint field returning 00-00-0000 / 0

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone tell me how to insert NULL properly? I can't seem to make it work.

My HTML form is populated with $product_lights_total and $product_releasedate. When they are NULL in the database, and I select that product to edit, in the HTML form those options appear empty/blank, but when I submit the form with no changes, upon refresh those fields become 0 and 00-00-0000.

I have a bunch of varchar(xx) columns that I update at the same time as the ones in this example, sometimes to NULL using the same method as below, and it works fine. Those stay NULL. I left them out of this example to keep the size down.

```
// First, grab the info needed to populate my HTML form for the selected product
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $get_item_stats = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id'");
}
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_item_stats);
if (!$row) {
    $error = 'Error.';
    $link = '.';
    include 'error.php';
    exit();
}
if ($row['lights_total'] == NULL) {
    $product_lights_total = NULL;
} else $product_lights_total = $row['lights_total'];
if ($row['releasedate'] == NULL) { 
    $product_releasedate = NULL; 
} else $product_releasedate = $row['releasedate'];

// if the form is submitted, insert the values present in the form
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $lights_total = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['lights_total']);
    $releasedate = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['releasedate']);

    $edit_item = "UPDATE products SET lights_total='$lights_total', releasedate='$releasedate' WHERE id='$productid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $edit_item);
    if (!$result) {
        $error = 'Error.';
        include 'error.php';
        exit();
    }
    else
        // do stuff
}
```

edit to show table structure:

```
releasedate DATE DEFAULT NULL,
lights_total tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL
```

If I select those values in mysql they return NULL (assuming that's what they were inserted as in my initial database population). They only change from NULL using this php code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not inserting `null`, you're actually inserting... `''`

This is because a PHP `null`, when cast to a string, is the empty string, and you are wrapping that empty string in MySQL quotes.

You *can* work around it:

```
"... releasedate = ".($releasedate ? "'".$releasedate."'" : "null")." ..."
```

But really you should be using prepared statements - pass a `null` to that and you will insert `null`, no troubles.

Comment: I have barely learned mysqli...I do really need to learn PDO I know, I've glanced at it before and it seemed a little over my head. I will google again and see if I can find a good tutorial.

Comment: @jotty Believe me, I thought the same ;) I've been stuck using the old `mysql_` functions because "they work for me and I know to be very careful!"... within an hour of learning PDO, I looked to my Past Self and called myself an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

Check data type of your date column it might be date or datetime it will not take null value. You can do one of following
either set default value for that column
or change datatype to varchar
or try with allowing null value in table structure
Hope this help :)

Comment: Sorry should have included that info, will update my post. releasedate is set to DATE DEFAULT NULL, and lights_total is tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL. When I select them in mysql they return NULL.

Answer (score 0):

*emphasized text*Firstly, you should actually check the values from your POST data to ensure they are of expected values - mysqli_real_escape_string() will offer some protection from SQL injection attacks but not all. If, after checking it is a valid "blank" value, then insert NULL

To do this,

```
UPDATE products SET lights_total=NULL, releasedate='$releasedate' WHERE id='$productid'";
```

No quotes on NULL

Or, to use a variable instead:

```
$lights_total = "NULL";
UPDATE products SET lights_total=$lights_total, releasedate='$releasedate' WHERE id='$productid'";
```

Quote NULL in this case

Comment: "you should actually check the values from your POST data to ensure they are of expected values" - Could you explain more here. I am an admitted newbie to a lot of this, what sort of methods are you referring to for checking expected values? Would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The PHP `NULL` will be added as `''` in your query. You need to change your code a bit :

```
$product_lights_total = $row['lights_total'] == NULL 
    ? "NULL" 
    : "'".$row['lights_total']."'";
$product_releasedate = $row['releasedate'] == NULL 
    ? "NULL" 
    : "'".$row['releasedate']."'";

//...

$edit_item = "
    UPDATE products 
    SET lights_total = $lights_total, 
        releasedate  = $releasedate
    WHERE id = $productid";

//...
```

Comment: This works, and if I leave a product that has a NULL releasedate as NULL, it stays that way on form submit. But if I try to put a date in place of null, it is inserting as 0000-00-00. Then it shows up in the form as '0000-00-00' (with the quotes) when I go to edit that product again. I can then put NULL in place of the '0000-00-00' and it reverts back to NULL though, that's good. But why would I be having trouble inserting an actual date?

Comment: Does your date fit *exactly* the `YYYY-mm-dd` format ?

Comment: Yup, if I use the original code I posted, and I put a date in place of the empty releasedate field on the form, the date gets inserted correctly...then appears correctly when I refresh the item for editing. I don't see why I can't do the same with your code, it looks like it should work just fine. hmm.

Comment: Hm, also, using your code. If the product has a date field that isnt null (ie, 1992-01-02), in my html form it appears with quotes as '1992-01-02'...could mean something? Again though, if I edit that date (while removing the quotes (it breaks otherwise)), it gets inserted as 0000-00-00.